# Sometimes tabs take long to open, with the firefox loading animation appearing for a long time

Tags: firefox, performance

Sometimes tabs take long to open. I keep seeing the loading animation firefox has for the tab but it takes long to disappear. This can sometimes be for 3, 5, 10 or 30 minutes.

Disabling or enabling hardware acceleration in the Firefox Settings doesn't help.

I'm using Windows 10 and Firefox 81

Comment: Is this a Firefox issues?  That is, no issue for Chrome or Edge?  If Firefox only, uninstall it and all settings and extensions, restart and reinstall Firefox. You may have an extension running causing this issue.

Comment: There's different methods for uninstalling Firefox. There is Refresh, restart with addons disabled, uninstall and deleting your profile, and uninstall and keeping your profile. Which one should I choose? I do not want to install Chrome as I read an article that says it tracks everything you type in on your keyboard and sends it to Google, and I read another article that says that Chrome also scans every file on your computer  allegedly for antivirus purposes so Chrome is spyware. I have not tried to see if I get the same issue in Edge.

Comment: "Refresh, restart with add-ons disabled, uninstall and deleting your profile, and uninstall and keeping your profile. "   <-- I suggest uninstall and delete profile to see if that fixes the issue. I have Firefox in a Linux Virtual Machine with no extensions or logged in Profile and performance is fine.

Comment: I tried to uninstall and delete my profile and it didn't work. When I opened firefox again after uninstalling and installing, my profile was still there. Also when installing and opening for the first time, Firefox had a window saying `Nearly done` and it kept loading forever and wouldn't finish.

Comment: Try the following: Go to your APPDATA folder and find the Mozilla folder. Within that delete the Firefox folder.  Close out, restart and test.

Comment: I have uninstalled Firefox, deleted the Mozilla APPDATA folder, restarted my computer then reinstalled Firefox. And I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: I will look around but I am not sure what else to suggest at this point.

Comment: I have also reinstalled all the extensions I had before. I do not know if the extensions are slowing down Firefox. I will restart with extensions disabled to see if that helps.

Comment: I have solved the problem now. Multiple things had to be done for it to be solved. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by performing multiple tasks as the solution is to do multiple things.

- Use Windows Update to update to the latest version of Windows 10 (In my circumstances, upgrading from Windows 10 1903 to Windows 10 20H2 made my computer faster, startup windows and applications faster, and freeze and crash less.)
- Upgrade Firefox to the latest version (In my circumstances upgrading from Firefox 80.1 to 81 made Firefox faster and crash and freeze less)
- Run a DISM Restore Health scan then a SFC scan afterwards. The instructions are [described here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system) and below. The scans take hours to run but my computer froze and crashes less when DISM got to 31% so it's best to wait for it to complete. The progress bar moves in discrete increments rather than continually, so the percentage complete shown jumps numbers giving the impression that it's not running when it is. Once done restart your computer.
- Disable extensions which are causing performance problems. You can use `Restart with addons disabled` in the `Help` menu or use *trial and error* to figure out which extension is causing the problem. Firefox extensions that cause performance problems tend not to cause issues in the first 2-3 minutes of Firefox running, but later on, with more issues the longer Firefox is running, so you have to wait. (In my instance, the *WAVE Accessibility Tool* was causing performance problems.)
- If you have Intel Rapid Storage Technology pre-installed on your computer, open it, and go to the Performance tab and disable Link Power Storage then restart your computer.
- Right click Firefox, click properties, then the compatibility tab and make sure it runs as administrator.
- Check if certain websites slow down the web browser as one tab of when opened in multiple tabs. (In my experience Metro.co.uk slows down Firefox significantly)
- Go to Control Panel then Network and Sharing Centre then Change adapter settings. Right click the adapter used for your wi-fi connection and click properties. When a new window appears, click Configure. When a new window appears, go the the Power Management tab and make sure that "turn off this device to save power" is unticked.
- Change the Power Plan under Power Options under Control Panel or right clicking the battery icon in the system tray. Change the power plan to `High Performance`. If it's not there, then edit the current power plan under `change plan settings` then `change advanced power settings` so that `turn off hard disk` is not turned off when idle and the wireless adapter is set to `maximum performance`.
- Restart the Windows Search and Superfetch or now called Sysmain service. If that doesn't work, disable it. It will take 5-10 minutes for the effects on the hard drive usage in task manager to happen.
- Make sure that Firefox runs as administrator by changing the properties of Firefox.exe Do the same for any backup programs you have running in the background. Restart the programs.
- Under the Properties window of the `Firefox.exe` go to the Security tab and give the current user all the permissions. Do the same for any backup programs you have in the background. Restart the programs.

> DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth

> sfc /scannow